# How to Stop Magento2 Default Newsletter Subscription Email

Tags: newsletter, magento-2.1.7

I want to stop Default Newsletter subscription in magento2 because I am already using **Ebizmarts_MageMonkey** module for that functionality.

Currently I am using Plugin to override `SendConfirmationSuccessEmail()`.

My code is `etc/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber">
    <plugin name="my-subscriber" type="Custom\Module\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber" setOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

and php file `Newsletter/Model/Subscribe.php` code is,

```
namespace Custom\Module\Newsletter\Model;

use Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber as MageSubscriber;

class Subscriber
{
    public function aroundSendConfirmationSuccessEmail(MageSubscriber $oSubject, callable $proceed) {}   
}
```

This is working fine but it stopped developer mode. Can anybody tell me where I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to actually disable output in the Magento Admin.

Go to Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Disable Modules Output. Select Mage_Newsletter and select “Disabled”. Save and you are done.

You can also disable the module completely from app/etc/modules. Open up Mage_All.xml and go to the Mage_Newsletter node. change active from true to false and save.